# Why do we have to cast the List returned by Collectors.toList() to List<Integer> even though the elements of the Stream are already mapped to Integer?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm mapping a raw `Stream` to a `Stream<Integer>` and then collect the elements to a `List<Integer>`.

Why do I have to cast the result of `collect(Collectors.toList())` to `List<Integer>` if my mapper - `.map(str -> ((String)str).length())` - already maps to `Integer`?

My code:

```
List list = Arrays.asList("test", "test2");
List<Integer> lengths = (List<Integer>) list.stream()
                                            .map(str -> ((String)str).length())
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I don't use a raw `List`, there's no need to cast:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("test", "test2");
List<Integer> lengths = list.stream()
                            .map(str -> str.length())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `List<Integer> lengths = list.stream().mapToInt(str -> ((String) str).length()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I know what a raw type is, and it's not a duplicate!

Comment: @isah please read my answer on the "Why does the Streams API need a hint" duplicate, especially "when you use a raw type, all generics are erased from the type, not just ones directly related to the omitted type."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `list.stream()` on a raw `List` produces a raw `Stream`. calling `map` on that `Stream` doesn't change that `Stream` to a generic `Stream<Integer>`. It changes it to another raw `Stream`. Therefore when you call `collect(Collectors.toList())`, you get a raw `List` and have to cast it to `(List<Integer>)`.

Conclusion : don't use raw types.

Comment: Thanks Eran. It seemed intuitive as the mapper maps to Integer.